# Morgan logger in an express app doesn't create new lines with each entry

Tags: node.js, express, logging, morgan

I'm having a problem getting the morgan logger module to write each log entry on a new line in my log file.

I've written an express app to authenticate users into a resource we subscribe to, and I need to add logging to the app. I have morgan set up to write to a file, however, each entry in the log file is written on the same line, instead of writing to a new line.

Here's what I have in my code

```
//requiring express and morgan
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');

//defining the file to write log entries to
var accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(path.join('logs', 'access.log'), {flags: 'a'});

//defining what to log with morgan
app.use(morgan(':date[iso], :remote-addr, :status, :response-time ms', {stream: accessLogStream}));
```

What am I missing? I tried adding /n to the end of the morgan format like:

```
app.use(morgan(':date[iso], :remote-addr, :status, :response-time ms /n', {stream: accessLogStream}));
```

but that resulted in an error. The error says:

```
undefined:8
(tokens["response-time](req, res) || "-") + " ms

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpeceted token
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Morgan actually writes with a new line: https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/blob/master/index.js#L130

Note that this is a unix newline. If you are on Windows you should read the file with an application that does render non-Windows newlines (i.e. not Notepad).

Comment: That was my problem! I was opening the log in Notepad. When I opened it using Notepad++ everything showed up on it's own line. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I was looking for that too.

make sure you have the latest [morgan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan) package installed.

This should do :

```
const express = require('express');
const expressApp = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');

expressApp.use(morgan(function (tokens, req, res) {
    return [
        '-------------------------\n', // <= horizontal line breaker added with every log
        tokens.method(req, res),
        tokens.url(req, res),
        tokens.status(req, res),
        tokens.res(req, res, 'content-length'), '-',
        tokens['response-time'](req, res), 'ms'
    ].join(' ')
}));
```

Hope this helps.
Thank you.